# Automorphisms of a K3 surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, k3-surfaces, automorphisms

I was studying the following algebraic surface in $\mathbb{P}^5$ defined by the following three quadrics:

\begin{cases}
    x^2 + xy + y^2=w^2\\
    x^2 + 3xz + z^2=t^2\\
    y^2 + 5yz + z^2=s^2.
    \end{cases}

It is a well-known result that its minimal resolution is a K3-surface, which we will denote by X. I am interested in finding out if we know anything about Aut(X). More specifically, if it has any element of infinite order or it is finite. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about the group of automorphisms defined over **C** or only those defined over **Q** ?

Comment: What is the Picard number of this K3 surface?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$. But any information about automorphisms over $\mathbb{Q}$ would be useful.

Comment: @user69559 I don't know.